# Can I call a functions.php file from a different URL?

Tags: functions, wp-remote-request

I have several(5+) sites that are very similar in functionality. With that I have the same amount of functions.php files and child themes.

What I'd like to do is have one common functions file and then a custom functions.php file for each individual site for more site-specific functionality.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You're going to have to copy the file/theme somehow, take a look at child themes, otherwise the method you've _literally_ asked for cannot be done, but the end goal you wanted is possible. A remote request is not a viable solution, and if it was, it would bring with it a ***massive*** performance drop

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think it was entirely possible, but thought there might have been something I wasn't aware of.